# Set first time new password for mysql by shell script

Tags: mysql, sh, redhat

I am trying to write a shell script for on premise system. OS is Red Hat.
My script is below one, in it all thing working fine except set new password from default generated password which one its fetching from file path **/etc/.mysql_secret**

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

# MYSQL DEPLOYMENT

#variables
hostId="localhost"
newPasswrod="password"
newDatabase="mydb"
newUser="mymysql"

#install mysql with rpm files.
echo "installing mysql with rpm files."
rpm -ivh perl-Data-Dumper-2.145-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh lib64numa1-2.0.12-1.mga7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh libaio-0.3.109-13.el7.x86_64.rpm

tar xvf MySQL-5.6.46-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-5.6.46-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-5.6.46-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh MySQL-client-5.6.46-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

rpm -e --nodeps "mariadb-libs-5.5.64-1.el7.x86_64"

rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.6.46-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

mysqlPasswordFile="/root/.mysql_secret"
echo "retrieve password from default location" 
#retrieve password from default location example with below parameter.
# The random password set for the root user at Mon Jan 13 11:00:59 2020 (local time): 4ug4P6drlfrN_vaE
mysqlPassword=` grep  '.*' $mysqlPasswordFile | cut -d : -f 4-`
mysqlPassword=`echo $mysqlPassword | sed 's/ *$//g'`
echo "default password is : $mysqlPassword"
# mysqlPassword=4ug4P6drlfrN_vaE 

# start mysql server
sudo service mysql start
echo "started mysql"

sleep 1s
# set new passwrd and create new user.
echo "set new passwrd and create new user"
if [ $mysqlPassword ] ; then
  mysql -u root -h "$hostId" -p"$mysqlPassword" -e "set password for root@'localhost'=password('$newPasswrod')"
  mysql -u root -h "$hostId" -p"$newPasswrod" -e "SHOW DATABASES"
  mysql -u root -h "$hostId" -p"$newPasswrod" -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
fi
```

Its throwing below error when its going to set new password

**ERROR 1862 (HY000): Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.**

New password set direct when try by below way:-

```
#Default password 4ug4P6drlfrN_vaE
mysql -u root -p4ug4P6drlfrN_vaE 
set password for root@'localhost'=password('mysql');
```

I want achieve this thing by shell script.

Comment: Do you know about the `-e` option for the mysql client? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute

Comment: He want to know alter set password by shell command. @Bill

Comment: -e means I know just for execute command.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one **--connect-expired-password**

```
  "default_password_lifetime = 0" >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
  mysql -u root -p<current dummy password> --connect-expired-password -e "SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new password');"
```